# OneToMany Relationship for more generic django apps

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how to genereate a one-to-many relation ship (i.e. a "list of objects for one model to the other) without having to use a foreign key on the child model. I want to achieve this because the child should be unaware of the parent to have a generic app.

Example:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    lease = models.ForeignKey('leaseapp.Lease')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

And my other app:

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    leaserholder = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Now I would like for a lease to have multiple payments, but without making my Payment Model specific to my lease app, it should be usable in other apps as well.

Was is the best practice here?

Comment: You must use either foreign key or one to one relationship to connect between both models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like generic relation. See: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) to django documentation. Generic foreign keys and relations sometimes cause issues in later development process but you can also consider this:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

And in leaseapp

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    leaserholder = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class LeasePayment(models.Model):
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
    payment = models.OneToOneField(Payment)
```

Advantage: there is no magic behind and your database model is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `GenericForeignKey`. To do this you need the `content_type`, `object_id` and `content_object` properties on the Payment model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class Payment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can create a lease payment like this. This will work for any model. So if you create a `Fee` model you can also create payments for that

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    leaserholder = models.CharField(max_length=300)

lease = Lease.object.first()
Payment.objects.create(content_object=lease, amount=700)
```

Note: this requires that `django.contrib.contenttypes` be installed, which is by default in most django apps. For more info [check out the docs page on contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)